# R monthly average from monthly time series data

Tags: r, statistics

Monthly rainfall data is in a time series from 1983 Jan. to 2012 Dec.

```
One.Month.RainfallSJ.inch <- window(TS.RainfallSJ_inch, start=c(1983, 1), end=c(2012, 12)) 
One.Month.RainfallSJ.inch

   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1983  7.41  4.87  5.92  3.90  0.15  0.00  0.00  0.02  1.08  0.19  5.26  3.82
1984  0.17  1.44  0.90  0.54  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.02  1.75  3.94  1.73
1985  0.74  0.76  2.98  0.48  0.23  0.00  0.13  0.00  0.35  0.98  2.47  1.40
1986  2.41  6.05  3.99  0.66  0.16  0.00  0.00  0.00  1.02  0.08  0.17  0.85
1987  1.60  2.10  1.87  0.14  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.93  1.65  3.31
1988  2.08  0.62  0.06  1.82  0.66  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.06  1.42  2.14
1989  1.06  1.07  1.91  0.57  0.09  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.83  1.33  0.80  0.04
1990  1.93  1.61  0.89  0.22  2.38  0.00  0.15  0.00  0.24  0.25  0.24  2.03
1991  0.18  2.22  6.17  0.18  0.15  0.06  0.00  0.04  0.12  0.85  0.43  2.43
1992  1.73  6.59  3.37  0.42  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.66  0.05  4.51
1993  6.98  4.71  2.81  0.54  0.47  0.54  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.67  2.17  1.99
1994  1.33  3.03  0.44  1.47  1.21  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.07  0.27  2.37  1.76
1995  8.66  0.53  6.85  1.06  1.27  0.84  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.05  4.71
1996  3.03  4.85  2.62  0.75  1.42  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  1.08  1.65  4.78
1997  6.80  0.14  0.17  0.11  0.55  0.21  0.00  0.51  0.00  0.69  5.01  1.85
1998  4.81 10.23  2.40  1.46  1.93  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.60  1.77  0.72
1999  3.25  2.88  2.69  1.56  0.02  0.14  0.14  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.50  0.55
2000  3.57  4.56  1.69  0.74  0.40  0.30  0.00  0.01  0.12  2.16  0.44  0.31
2001  2.87  4.44  1.71  1.48  0.00  0.13  0.00  0.00  0.13  0.12  2.12  4.47
2002  0.75  0.81  1.80  0.35  0.68  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  1.99  6.60
2003  0.65  1.65  0.77  2.95  0.72  0.00  0.00  0.03  0.03  0.00  1.91  4.91
2004  1.61  4.28  0.49  0.40  0.08  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.15  3.04  0.73  4.32
2005  3.47  5.31  3.55  2.52  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.10  0.45  5.47
2006  2.94  2.39  6.55  4.55  0.45  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.39  1.38  1.77
2007  0.93  3.49  0.46  0.96  0.08  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.26  1.13  0.55  1.18
2008  5.81  1.81  0.15  0.03  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.19  1.33  1.53
2009  1.30  5.16  1.89  0.30  0.09  0.01  0.00  0.02  0.19  2.41  0.41  2.16
2010  4.58  2.12  2.05  3.03  0.35  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.25  1.76  2.53
2011  0.96  3.15  4.32  0.20  0.40  1.51  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.77  0.08  0.08
2012  0.90  0.63  1.98  1.88  0.00  0.15  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.35  2.59  4.24
```

How can I code Jan. average value from 1983 to 2012 and so on? 
Thanks,

Nahm

Comment: `colMeans(One.Month.RainfallSJ.inch)` maybe?

Comment: yes it works with MatrixRain <- as.matrix(MonthlyRainfall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maybe `colMeans`

```
colMeans(One.Month.RainfallSJ.inch)
#       Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov 
# 2.8170000 3.1166667 2.4483333 1.1756667 0.4646667 0.1386667 0.0150000 0.0210000 0.1560000 0.7100000 1.5230000 
#       Dec 
# 2.6063333
```